# Néron-Severi groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over the complex numbers.

Let $$c_1 : \text{Pic}(X)\to H^2(X,\mathbf{Z}(1))$$

Its kernel is the subgroup of homologically trivial divisor classes on $X$.
How does the proof that
$$\text{im}(c_1) = \text{NS}(X)$$
go?

I can't track a source, and there is some content in it.

Comment: What is $NS(X)$ mean for you?

Comment: Group of divisors up to algebraic equivalence

Comment: While commenting, it is advisable to use @[the name of the user] so that the user in question gets notified.

Comment: What does $\mathbf{Z}(1)$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

One way to define the Neron-Severi group $NS(X)$ is to fit it into the short exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}^0(X) \rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}(X) \rightarrow NS(X) \rightarrow 0$$ ($0$ being the appropriate identity). We also have the exponential sheaf sequence $$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathcal O \rightarrow \mathcal O^* \rightarrow 0$$ and, using the fact that $\mathrm{Pic}(X) \simeq H^1(X, \mathcal O^*)$ (Hartshorne, Ex. III.4.5), the long exact sequence of cohomology associated to this sheaf sequence gives us this map $c_1: \mathrm{Pic}(X) \to H^2(X, \mathbb Z)$. Now use the fact that $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X) = \ker c_1$ and an isomorphism theorem.

An interesting case of this is for K3 surfaces $X$.  By definition, $H^1(X, \mathcal O) = 0$, so $c_1: \mathrm{Pic}(X) \hookrightarrow H^1(X, \mathbb Z)$ is an injection, and $NS(X)$ is identified with $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$.

Comment: The definition the OP is using is via algebraic equivalence, so without showing the equivalence between the two definitions I'm not sure this answers the question.